# Finding a visually similar image on local storage

Tags: search, photos

I have a contact photo that I retrieved from google contacts. It's aspect ratio is 1:1 and resolution of 80 x 80 pixels.

A few years ago I set it as a contact picture for one of my contacts but have 'lost' it since then. I am trying to find it in the pictures I have stored on my HDD.

The original was not 1:1 but 9:16 (portrait).

Can anybody instruct me on the best way possible to find visually similar photos (keep in mind the different aspect ratios).

I have tried some software with no luck. Here is the list of software I tried:
DupliFinder, VSDuplicateImageFinder (MindGems), Dup Detector.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what operating system you are using so I will give you an option for windows. I have had really good luck in the past with [Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder](http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html). It is able to find photos that have been cropped to different aspect ratios as well as photos that have had various effects applied.

The software is completely free and, while it hasn't been updated in a few years, it has worked fine for me on Windows 10.

Comment: thank you it worked should I mark you answer somehow I can't seem to figure it out